# JavaScript rounding up to get 2nd decimal place 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

How am I to get second decimal place 0?

For example:

```
15.296326 => 15.30
15.245152 => 15.20
```

I have tried `toFixed()` and `Math.Floor` but could not get the expected answer.

Comment: What rounding algorithm do you use? How is it possible to derive `15.50` out of `15.245152`?

Comment: @VisioN that was 20 sorry for the typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function roundFloat(n) {
    return (Math.round(n * 10) / 10).toFixed(2);
}

roundFloat(15.296326);  // "15.30"
roundFloat(15.245152);  // "15.20"
```